# ElasticSearch 6.8 Java library: when sending an UpdateRequest overwrite a field of type Object instead of merging

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-6.8

We are using the Java library for Elastic Search version 6.8. We are trying to send an UpdateRequest to do partial updates to our fields. A couple of our fields are Objects (-> maps: key, value)

When sending a request for example:

```
    var updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
    updateRequest.index(...);
    updateRequest.type(...);
    updateRequest.id(...);

    Map<String, List<String>> mapWithEntries = Map.of("Main", List.of("test@test.com"));

    XContentBuilder content = jsonBuilder()
            .startObject()
            .field("emails", mapWithEntries)
            .endObject();

    updateRequest.doc(content);
    updateRequest.fetchSource(true);
    updateRequest.docAsUpsert(false);
    return updateRequest;
```

We notice that our new "mapWithEntries" gets merged with the existing map values for the field "emails". Noted that the documentation at [update by merging documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-update.html) does describe this behaviour.

Is it possible to overwrite the existing value for "emails" that only the newly "mapWithEntries" is available?
-> updating via script would cause a lot of rework.